# Update specific key/value of json object inside json array using MySQL syntax

Tags: mysql, mysql-json

I have MySQL 5.7.12 DB with a table that has a JSON column.

The data in the column as the following structure (json array may contain more than 2 json-objects:

`[{"ste": "I", "tpe": "PS"}, {"ste": "I", "tpe": "PB"}]`

I would like to craft an `UPDATE` query that changes the value of `ste`  where `tpe=PB`.

Here is my attempt:

`UPDATE user SET ext = JSON_SET(JSON_SEARCH(ext, 'one', 'PB', NULL, '$**.tpe'), '$.tpe', 'A');`

The output if the query should give:

`[{"ste": "I", "tpe": "PS"}, {"ste": "A", "tpe": "PB"}]`

It doesn't work - it updates the column to be:

`"$[0].tpe"`

How can I make this work?

**EDIT**

I think this makes more sense but still something wrong with syntax

```
UPDATE user SET ext = JSON_SET(ext->JSON_SEARCH(ext, 'one', 'PS', NULL, '$**.tpe'), '$.tpe', 'A');
```

Comment: update your system to the last subversion

Answer (score 1):

If this is still needed.

JSON_SEARCH is giving output with quotes, so first you have to replace quotes.

**Syntax :**

```
UPDATE table_name SET json_col_name=JSON_SET(json_col_name, replace(JSON_SEARCH(json_col_name, 'one' ,'search_value') , "\"",""),'replace_value')
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand question correctly **ext** column of **user** table has below value

```
[{"ste": "I", "tpe": "PS"}, {"ste": "I", "tpe": "PB"}]
```

and ask is for UPDATE Query to modify 2nd index of value like below

```
[{"ste": "I", "tpe": "PS"}, {"ste": "A", "tpe": "PB"}]
```

**Recommended & Easy Solution based on Problem Statement considering json structure is fixed**

Update Query based on Json array index

```
update user set ext = JSON_SET(ext, '$[1].ste', 'A') where primary_key = 'primary_key_criteria';

select ext from user where primary_key = 'primary_key_criteria';
```

**Output after Update**

```
[{"ste": "I", "tpe": "PS"}, {"ste": "A", "tpe": "PB"}]
```

Comment: You can't use `'$[1].ste` in the query because the json array might contains more json objects. that's why we need to use `JSON_SEARCH` for searching for certain criteria, e.g: `tpe=PB`.

Comment: @Shvalb : It looks question was not clear & I clearly mentioned in answer that index solution is based on assumption if we want to update particular record. Will try again..
Down vote is discouraging :(

Comment: I'm sorry! didn't mean that! I actually impressed with your detailed answer of breaking my question into pieces.

Answer (score 0):

Hope you still need this.

Try using variable path in you `JSON_SET`. Use `JSON_SEARCH` to get the variable path the replace the the *absolute path* `tpe` with `ste` to update its value. Works for me!

```
update user set ext= JSON_SET(ext, REPLACE(REPLACE(JSON_SEARCH(ext, 'one', 'PB'),'"',''),'tpe','ste'), 'A');
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).